# Linking to cocoa libraries with CMake (C++ intermixed with Objective-C)

Tags: c++, objective-c, cmake

I'm working on adding cross platform clipboard support to my gui api. I managed to get it working on Windows nicely, now I'm on to OSX.

I've gotten the functions working like I want them, but the file is .mm . Therefore when people compile the OSX version of my gui, they now need to link against the cocoa library.

Does anyone have experience with how to link to cocoa when using cmake and intermixing c++ with objective-c?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some compiler switches which you pass to gcc or to clang to enable compilation of Objective C or Objective C++ applications:

```
gcc -ObjC MySourceFile.m 
gcc -ObjC++ MySourceFile.mm

clang -ObjC MySourceFile.m 
clang -ObjC++ MySourceFile.mm
```

You specify which the minimum version of MacOSX on which your app can run with the following option:

```
gcc -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
```

Specify 10.6 if you if want your app to be compatible with Snow Leopard. You also need to pass the sysroot option to gcc or clang to let them know which version of the SDK to compile against:

```
gcc -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 --sysroot=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
```

Toy specify the architecture to build with with the arch option

```
gcc -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 --sysroot=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -arch x86_64
```

If you are invoking the linker ld separately, then you need to pass the sysrootlib option to ld. To produce a dynamically linked library you pass the dylib option to ld. This is passed to ld if you pass the dynamiclib to gcc or clang.

```
gcc -dynamiclib -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 --sysroot=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -arch x86_64
```

To link against Cocoa Frameworks you pass framework option as a linker option to gcc and the name of the framework:

```
gcc -dynamiclib -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 --sysroot=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -arch x86_64 -Wl,-framework,Cocoa
```

If you use the C++ standard library you will need to specify that as a linker option with

```
-Wl,stdc++
```

When deploying to MacOSX 10.7 and compiling with clang you can use the libc++ C++ standard library. You pass an option to the compiler and to the linker:

```
-stdlib=libc++ -Wl,c++
```

So to produce a library from your source which is linked against the Cocoa framework, you would do the following using gcc

```
gcc -dynamiclib -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 --sysroot=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -arch x86_64 -o MyLibrary.dylib -Wl,-framework,Cocoa MySourceFile.mm
```

Hope this helps.